# Querying Azure synctable from iOS client predicate issue?

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using predicate on date attribute of sync table in azure pulltoquery method to sync. Requirment is get item  only for past 2 days.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *twoDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-2*24*60*60];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSString *toString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:twoDaysAgo];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(updatedAt>= %@)",toString];
```

but i am getting error from azure services      Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'GreaterThanOrEqual'.

Here the sample code provided by microsoft. Look for below method in the link provided.

-(void)pullData:(QSCompletionBlock)completion

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-offline-data/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with your date formatting. Try sending the query with a REST client like Fiddler or Postman and check it against your query on the client.

Note that this updated query is incompatible with incremental sync. So, you need to pass nil for the query key (the first parameter to pullData).

Comment: So you mean my predicate is right but date format is wrong?  I have tried with static date as will it says "ERROR Error Domain=com.Microsoft..  Code=-1400 "The predicate is not supported."                                       Also  In pullData method we have to pass queryId, in example it fetches all the data irrespective of incremental sync. What will be the queryId for incremental sync.
          [self.syncTable pullWithQuery:query queryId:@"allTodoItems" completion:^(NSError *error) {
              [self logErrorIfNotNil:error];
          }];
      }

Comment: If you use a query ID, then you are using incremental sync. Any string will work as a query ID. For an example of date querying, see the MSQuery tests: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/test/iOS/ZumoE2ETestApp/ZumoE2ETestApp/ZumoQueryTests.m#L82

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSDate in as parameter for your NSPredicate (or MSDateOffset if you data is DateTimeOffset):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(updatedAt>= %@)", twoDaysAgo];
```

Predicate parser in Azure Mobile SDK will use you parameter data type to create correct query string.

If your data type is of DateTimeOffset type:

```
MSDateOffset *offset = [MSDateOffset date:twoDaysAgo];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(updatedAt>= %@)", offset];
```